# How to zip multiple-feature (2D) and label (1D) arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array for the inputs and a 1D array for the binary labels.

```py
import numpy as np

inputs = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
labels = np.array([0, 1, 0])
```

The expected output is

```py
[[[1, 2, 3], 0]
 [[4, 5, 6], 1]
 [[7, 8, 9], 0]]
```

I have tried various numpy stack functions but they are asking for arrays with the same shape. I have also tried using `np.column_stack((inputs, labels))` but it flattens the input rows like this:

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 0]
 [4, 5, 6, 1]
 [7, 8, 9, 0]]
```

My current workaround is to use `np.array(list(zip(inputs, labels)))` but I do not know if it is an efficient solution to my problem.

Comment: Expected output is not a 'normal' array. Forget about efficiency.  Stick with lists, `ist(zip(inputs, labels))`  Or use that (3,4) array, `arr[:,:-1]` and `arr[:,-1]`

Comment: A numpy array is not a good data type for your expected output (the ndarray works best with numerical types, yours is a combination of lists and integers). Depending on what you are planning to do, keeping them separate is usually not a problem. In case you want to perform aggregations etc with the labels, I would recommend to have a look at the `pandas` library.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @CarlosHorn For my machine learning homework I have to do everything using only `numpy`, so I am not allowed to import other libraries. I will follow the latter recommendation of @hpaulj